# HTML Export and "org block"

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, html

Using EmacsMac 28.1 (OSX) (started as emacs -q), I'm trying to export a simple org document that contains an org source block:

```
#+begin_src org
*Hello* /world/
#+end_src
```

When I export this to a buffer (`C-c C-e h H`), the block is exported as:

```
...
<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-org">*Hello* /world/
</pre></div>
...
```

I would like to have the **Hello** in bold and the **world** in italic but I cannot identify which option to set. The answer is probably pretty obvious but I'm stuck.

Comment: It was more or less obvious `(require 'htmlize)` + `(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type 'css)` (htmlize is at https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize)

Comment: Please make your comment into an answer (and expand it a bit to explain what `org-html-htmlize-output-type` does). You can then accept your own answer. This way, future visitors will be able to see that the question has an accepted answer when searching to solve this or a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [htmlize](https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize) and optionally set the output type to 'css or 'inline-css then:

```
(require 'htmlize)
(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type 'css)
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add an explanation of what the variable does? What does it mean to give it the value `css`? What other values does it take? What was the (presumably default) value before you changed it? What led you to this variable? I'm asking because I don't know the answers and it is certainly not obvious to me why/how the solution works. I promise to upvote :-)